# How to Assert Object Equality, just for code coverage in MSTest?

Tags: c#, code-coverage, mstest

How do I make my  object's properties equality Assertion in MSTest, better. This is just to satisfy code coverage tool.

For Object:

```
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedContact.Address1, actualContact.Address1);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedContact.Address2, actualContact.Address2);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedContact.Address3, actualContact.Address3);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedContact.AddressType, actualContact.AddressType);
```

For Collections:

```
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expectedContacts, actualContacts);
```

What I tried:
1. Assert.AreEqual(expectedContact, actualContact)  properties.

2. [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/) -> not supported in MsTest.
3. Recursive comparison of properties

> still code coverage tool would complain about missing property
>   coverage

Comment: Writing a tests to only satisfy a test coverage tool is bad investment of time, IMO